# Excel Pivot Table - Multiple headers with subheaders

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot, excel-pivot

Is it possible to create a pivot table with multiple headers, and each header has multiple subheaders? I've been trying to figure out but couldn't find a way on how to do it right.

**This is my current table (raw data)**

[image]

**This is what I want to see in my pivot table.**

[image: This is my current table]

**But instead, it produces this result**
[image]

[image]

Hope you could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a word, no, at least not with your data structure. You'd need three columns: Department, Type (desktop/Laptop) and then the Item name.

Comment: I’m not understanding the delta from what you want. It looks like if you turn off the grand totals on rows and columns you have a perfect match to what you want. What am I missing?